# mysql - If I update one row, all the other rows (including updated row) return updated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a "activation" system for my website. There is a column called "active" in my DB, by default its value is the string "no" If i want to activate any user's account, I change active's value to "yes" Everything was working fine till i started to active a couple of accounts. After activating a single account (admin account), i echoed the value of the row active to see if everything was working fine, it printed "yes" But when i tried to login with unactivated accounts and echoed the value of the row active, they too returned "yes" But when i check in the DB, it says "no" When I don't activate any account (that is, if i dont change the active value of any account), all the accounts return "no" but when i try to activate one/more accounts all of them return "yes" I'm confused.

Code i used to create the column:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD active varchar(3) DEFAULT 'no'
```

Note: I'm changing active's value by clicking on its content and editing it.

EDIT1:

```
$res= mysql_query("SELECT active FROM users");
$row= mysql_result($res, 0);

    echo $row;
```

If i edit one/more active values, all of them return the same.

EDIT2:

UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE `db_name`.`users` SET `active` = 'yes' WHERE `users`.`id` =3;
```

Comment: What's your update statement look like? Sounds Like your where clause is always returning true

Comment: What statement are you using to activate a user?

Comment: As i stated already, I'm not using an update statement. I'm altering the value by clicking on the content and editing it.

Comment: There's clearly a problem in your code somewhere but if you don't post it there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: When you click and edit the content, there should be an update query in the backend that edits the data and saves to the DB right?? What is **THAT** update query??

Comment: Updated the OP with everything.

Comment: Something else is going on - that statement shouldn't be updating everybody.  Are you sure you're printing everybody out, and not holding over the value somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
mysql_query("SELECT active FROM users");
```

it should also be:

```
mysql_query("SELECT active FROM users WHERE id = 3");
```

The previous query just selects the value of active for the first user it finds in the table (always and only the first user in the table).
If you want to know the value of active for a *specific* user, you need to pass the id and select based on that.

Comment: Basing on your answer, my code should be `mysql_query("SELECT active FROM users WHERE username = $username");`

Comment: I edited my code, now the mysql_result() is returning a boolean instead of the value.

Comment: it will now not be returning a rowset, but a single value... ?

Comment: Also should that be "username = $username" or "username ='$username'" ?

Comment: My bad, it should be "username ='$username'". And yes, single value is all i need. But a new problem. it gives me some error "session_register() is deprecated ....."

Comment: Different enough to be a new question ;)

Comment: Aha, no problem, figured it out anyway. used session_start(); instead. Thanks for all the help. :)